# Apache / ColdFusion: Replicated Websites?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, content-management-system, dynamic-data, coldfusion-9

So I've done this before a number of different ways, but I wanted to get the opinion of the community.

What needs to be accomplished is essentially dynamic URLs that pull in content depending on what exists in the URL. Example:

http://www.domain.com/userA/

This URL would pull in userA's content and populate the website. The idea is so multiple people can have their own custom spot on the website. It's the same website for everyone, but the user specific information changes per the URL request.

Taking this a step further, to be able to call example.com/userA/mediaID and display a video from userA.

Like I said, I've done this before, but I want to do it with best practices in mind... perhaps a combination of htaccess and CGI?

Thoughts?

Comment: Where is the content coming from? Are you pulling it across the network from other servers, or just from other folders on the same Web server?

Comment: Eventually, I'd like to be able to use a cloud server for this... but at first, same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any CF developers that are familiar with Routing for Rails or .NET MVC, check out: http://cfwheels.org/

Wheels is an open-source CFML Routing System! Might be a winner!

Answer (score 3):

Use the Apache [rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to send the request through a [front controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). So your httpd.conf would have an entry that looks something like this:

```
# QSA preserves original query string 
# PT Sends the new URI to ColdFusion 
# NS (No [internal] Subrequests) is necessary because expandPath() will not work otherwise
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /frontcontroller.cfm [E=ORIGINAL_URI:%{REQUEST_URI},QSA,PT,NS]
```

This makes `CGI.ORIGINAL_URI` available to ColdFusion code this allows for dynamically generating the response and securing it relative to the user session.

Answer (score 0):

Other languages/frameworks do this dynamically using a 'routes' file which uses application mappings rather than the `.htaccess` (see [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)).

Perhaps you could replicate this in some way in CF - but I haven't tried - generally URL rewriting will work fine in most cases.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, .NET MVC has a wonderful routing system... I've built my own, but there must be something else "semi-official".